# $ \beta(x) = \lbrace B \in \beta : x\in B \rbrace$ is a base of neighborhoods of $ x $

Tags: general-topology

If $\beta$ is a base for the topology $ \tau $ in $ X $, and $ x\in X $, then the collection $ \beta(x) = \lbrace B \in \beta : x\in B \rbrace$ is a base of neighborhoods of $ x $.

Let $ U \in\nu (x) $. I need to find a neighborhood $ B \in \beta (x) $ such that $ B \subseteq U $. Now, since $ \beta $ is a base for $ \tau $, there exists $ B \in \beta$ such that $ x \in B \subseteq U $. Then I do not know how to relate this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system

Comment: You have $x \in B \subseteq U$ and $B \in \beta$ doen't that prove $B \in \beta (x) $ which is what you wanted or what is it that you want to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\beta$ is a base, the open set $U$ can be written as the union of a subclass of $\beta$, say, $\beta'$, so $U=\displaystyle\bigcup_{B\in\beta'}B$, so for $x\in U$, some $B\in\beta'\subseteq\beta$ is found such that $x\in B$. As $B\in\beta$, so $B\in\beta(x)$.